# Use RDS or a container (ECS) for database? Advantages and disadvantages

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-rds, amazon-ecs

I want to host a database on AWS. RDS is one option but I have heard something about containers (and ECS). I see containers as useful for testing, but I'm uncertain about running a production database on one. What would be the advantages and disadvantages of each of them?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Run a database yourself on an EC2 instance**:

- You choose the database
- You control all the configuration
- You control what else runs on that machine
- Backup, restoration, and other tasks can be customized
- You are wholly responsible for keeping the DB running
- You are wholly responsible for backups

**Run a database on RDS**:

- Limited selection of DBs
- You can run Aurora, Amazon's proprietary DB
- Some (few) configuration options are not permitted
- No access to the underlying machine
- Automatic backups
- Basic maintenance is automated
- You can't run a cheaper DB than the smallest machine Amazon will rent

**Run a database inside a container on an EC2 instance**:

*All the advantages & disadvantages of running the DB yourself, plus*

- You have to do some extra work to persist data across containers
- You can easily run the exact same DB setup for local development, in test, and in production
- You pay some additional overhead (small)
- Process isolation makes it easy to share a machine (maybe your entire workload is less than a t2.micro)

Running a DB in a container under ECS doesn't really get you advantages over managing the containers yourself. But if you're using ECS for the rest of your stack and you're putting the DB in a container, then you'd just want to use ECS for that also.

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer. So using the RDS does not need a database admin then?

Comment: @Sarah that depends on what you think a "database admin" does. Historically, a DBA has deep understanding of SQL and architects the schema and helps improve query performance. RDS does none of that for you -- it just does nightly backups and automatic upgrades.

Comment: You left off some advantages of RDS such as the easy configuration of hot-standby instances and read replicas, and the automatic failover to a hot-standby if the primary server fails.

Comment: agree with @MarkB there are a few advantages you've missed for RDS but a good answer

Comment: What about connecting RDS to container? then would it be possible to have both of them on Local server?

Comment: @Sarah "connecting RDS to container" doesn't make any sense to me; I think you're confused about RDS, containers, or both.

Comment: I mean if I use container for my test env for testing locally , and use RDS for DB, then can I use/access database of my RDS on my local env?

Comment: @Sarah OK, but then what's the container for?

Comment: For running some applications

Comment: @Sarah I believe you are misunderstanding some aspects and this comment field doesn't give me the bandwidth to explain everything. I think you need to either spend some more time experimenting on your own or find someone to give you a hand.

Comment: Well, I was meaning something like this link: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-connect-to-an-Amazon-RDS-instance-from-my-Docker-container           Anyway thanks a lot for all your help.

Comment: One of the best resumed answers for that question that I saw until now. Thanks.