# Shall I use AWS ECS with a Postgres Docker container or AWS RDS?

Tags: node.js, docker, amazon-rds, amazon-ecs, docker-container

I'm just using two docker containers for my node.js app server and for my Postgres DB.

Is it a good idea to deploy the app, specially for persistent data (my database) in a volume, through AWS ECS or I should stick on RDS for that purpose?

I keep on reading different opinions about it and I am still confused weather or not I should use docker container for databases instead of RDS or the otherway around.

Can anyone share their experience with these aproaches and their differences?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39078912/use-rds-or-a-container-ecs-for-database-advantages-and-disadvantages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you deployed to ECS you would have to use EC2 deployment target type and bind to an EBS volume path (which is single-AZ), or you would use Fargate with an EFS volume path (which is slow).

By contrast RDS is designed to provide you with multi-AZ, fault-tolerant database deployments. In addition, RDS also provides management of database upgrades, automated backups, etc. You get much more features with RDS, than you do by trying to deploy and manage a database server yourself on ECS.